# How to find the area between 2 curves given an interval

Tags: integration, area

> Determine the area of the region within the interval $[0, 1]$ bounded by the curves $f(x)=2 \sin (x)$ and $g(x)=\displaystyle\frac{4-x}{2}$ correct to $2$ decimal places.

---

The first thing I did was:
$\int _0^{\pi }\:2\sin\left(x\right)-\left(\frac{4-x}{2}\right)$
and I got: $4-\frac{8\pi -\pi ^2}{4}$ or $0.18$
but my textbook answer gives: 4.29 units

I then graph this on Geogebra and get:

[image]

[image]

So is it the other way around? $g(x) - f(x)$? Also does this means that I should always visualise or graph the functions first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The area to be calculated is: $A1+A2+A3$. Sanity check: the area $A1$ is less than $1$ (compare with triangle side 2 and height 1); the area of $A2$ is slightly more than $A1$. So, the total area should be around $2$, not $4$.

---

To calculate exactly, first you need to find the intersection points:
$$2\sin x=2-\frac x2 \Rightarrow x_1\approx 0.89,x_2\approx 2.85$$
Next you need to break up the interval:
$$A=A1+A2+A3=\int_0^{0.89} \left(2-\frac x2-2\sin x\right)dx+\int_{0.89}^{2.85}\left(2\sin x-2+\frac x2\right)dx+\int_{2.85}^{\pi} \left(2-\frac x2-2\sin x\right)dx\approx 1.99.$$
WolframAlpha answers: [Intersection points](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%202sinx%3D2-x%2F2%20for%200%3Cx%3Cpi) and [the total area](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%282-x%2F2-2sinx%2C0%2C0.89%29%2Bintegral%282sinx-2%2Bx%2F2%2C0.89%2C2.85%29%2Bintegral%282-x%2F2-2sinx%2C2.85%2Cpi%29).

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, but my textbook gives 4.29unit squared???

Comment: That is what I implied by the sanity check: there is something wrong with this task. Maybe some misprint?

Comment: You are welcome. Let us know when you find out the truth.

Comment: Right I see, Thank you. Also Do you mind taking a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749325/how-to-derive-a-first-order-differential-equation-from-a-slope-field? Its about differential equation, its unanswered yet :)

Answer (score -1):

For the area between the curves you have the right idea, just you need to count all area as positive (unsigned area). Try using $$\int_0^\pi|f(x)-g(x)|dx$$